# Error seen while calling Java file from Python script

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, java-8

Below is the Java program which I want to execute using Python script from Pycharm:

```
public class ExampleWithField {
    public int member = 1;
    public String member() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Below is the Python code

```
from  py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()
example = gateway.jvm.ExampleWithField()
c = example.member()
print c
```

And I am getting error like

```
File "C:/Users/pmevega/PycharmProjects/untitled1/First.py", line 16, in <module>
    example = gateway.jvm.ExampleWithField()
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```